# openssl_decrypt and aes-256-gcm doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, cryptography

I'm building a web app that gets data fed to it by a webhook but I can't seem to decrypt it. I've heard that Laravel does not support aes-256-gcm but OpenSSL does so what's the issue.

I'm trying to write the result to a text file but each time the text file remains blank. The headers and body are populating correctly as I've outputted them to a text file and seen them.

I don't even seem to be getting any errors either.

```php
$key_from_configuration = '30053D479609E8D9EF51B2413AD9AE973F9C3075A4ED504122D2FA1842E23FCC';
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    if($header == 'X-Initialization-Vector') {
        $iv_from_http_header = $value;
    }
    if($header == 'X-Authentication-Tag') {
        $auth_tag_from_http_header = $value;
    }
}
$http_body = substr(substr($request, strpos($request, 'Body":"') + 7), 0, -2);

$key = hex2bin($key_from_configuration);
$iv = hex2bin($iv_from_http_header);
$auth_tag = hex2bin($auth_tag_from_http_header);
$cipher_text = hex2bin($http_body);

$result = openssl_decrypt($cipher_text, "aes-256-gcm", $key, 0, $iv, $auth_tag);

Storage::put('test.txt', $auth_tag_from_http_header);
Storage::put('test-body.txt',  $result);
```

Here's the data I'm getting from the webhook:

```
iv_from_http_header:
8CDA0460B60E68461906CF65

auth_tag_from_http_header:
77B1C17C8AE2B4237A57468C53691A40

data:
D1D2CBE86A8361388FC902608844E30BF7CC3DC9EE94AFDD2E89D71E45573C5EEB325B89B1EC94BD
E4344BF75183263A0857D4B5328DFE5F864A8F550DB1F45285AB90B1AD0D4AB97006D4357BB8ECB5
43A82B96A0ED80280AE26E67ED5937700F524012C1AABBF65774CC45E508C1A73D2AF2CF0D17B416
B728D43CC8C2420B4C720DC3F66601B68443EB95A6340E00E86D16E2997215BED8DEA5625B7A58C0
62ABFCE7AEA52C7442E69C243FBC22CABA4AFD51BD13B645DDE4284A8FB255CA9D4A751BEF4BAF7A
777ABED7DB88C8A0DB54DE0582285759D56C396D4B1E8F54B532D3297EDF5EE58604CE25AE753CDA
0E7CF7A027BB228CA8C8208CFD57D2239FB46C07B42E09BA51CE1BFC8B378CD06D68A75AFAFF6109
23D4F5C97E552C5932707801FA3DDA413AE235BFE0A181DCF7C45641A0B568274A214A8BFC133858
F291FF0659CAEDB51E2D6D598E01619266923C02BF3E185243D69B1C7A89EDF892957DF89FE5E40E
CACEE02029A9C1089EA827AD923394B77FAD6FD908CB5F0D7D9EE879DCE802F9C6BE111ED06F1FF3
03093D4338A2577F3B868CEE17DCEC2D9B9FA8D8601D8B79CD1F9BCB7DA458AD8A703AF8C1BDFF6D
255A1E4861A556BCB7636FC8BE996034EC2A7A2D296BA6EADD9A5002540850257B6AB7E60FA4C58E
022E27ED49AAF7FFF5689A1F669298D07CCA2400450A5E24DFD1DD1A6332EE6760A3431C4D8EF326
54E182932D18193956FDA57447B6BDE58A5F69484896E5B4FACB35AD7C09FA5D052C360A7BB70AB4
7010606751CF53EA37785BFC4A9F2D70E197B2E6E643A4FE9C13CAE66C716F149040026D864D99AE
54A8879BDBF171403611D502F625582DEC6C1E00008994C30C28358356192F89343CB43C883630AC
F2E84A4239499A1E5216046FE8E5219455A26FCBDA2EDA76D06786EADCB52AF76F1A484D3B9790FB
77E24DB261405705FED0A6F8B4BD520229AE21D7053283912F4D4546723A5E4C6537D3D3844BB9C2
CC4AC43A2FF081C500788304A8F754B5B103634BDBB7EBD99482FB210A506B13CF9F63821E75A0C0
DB1EE1ABDF546F7694192BBE208389A32BF383946C368CF199CCD283DB863E4B49767ED23B2ED073
25AA2F59F02399DEA16A41A0275B83921DE4DEDA6A721DD78DBC6DE4583D92AA620876FD652A08D8
6422DA71915F6D0BB393D61812B26B3705E4270C5ADA02AA4F3ADBA55B8E58AF5792E3D468680DEC
BC19A732F2946D5F6E1C1A9439416C704D3B531B4649C7CB184F0A22A3FBD6C90CADA04C613F650C
D2668B9C3E2B217D79B5E6B1686874A382D90CC5EEA42444EE270FE73CCC8133E77AE828DA1EB4C8
9D61437EF9CECE2E0B0139F3787C0913FFAD15D24E57DC2ACA44F4FE17B5D047F0573B5A98D91C6B
EA856F6308FD9CAFB9A7CBF02440F2BF655073956127A8F8F8B6E949AFB3D69F7D4A0CF42888B44C
DEA4C60635ADE7A01007A8A8D4E382E29EAF94011A8EDD16447B6946337D352858A3FAD6FF34DF28
3C8228B9F75FE3C828B3A3A6D08DCE0F486A27CAF4C2AC6110A0BBA5459C28B39F96DFBC8F380A56
C3FF449EBE7F0E5B2A716743A5AB1230C4C733589E3A621298A504DAFFD62827070332CDDAD34299
77AE61F1B31EF5ACB89CACBE69AD3DA40B822A8819C049A450DA367CB9A7AB6D285D6B2DBCEA62CB
0552BD39EED60776A81E1675268E450B7980BD3A0D96134789D046E422E0D881BC8DF44608E1ED72
79AE245E82D4C13C9E8C4A9A4D22C2B241116EB4A28CCD142FF1F665E54C4463332CAA7DA61AD933
E083318A597C8064AD6BC402D4D2D959F224062B770FA4D6DD435CD74232ADC69462A09CBBB845FC
48BB0B80E3D0DC2730C6C17A27CA783AE56FD68C
```

Comment: What does the HTTP request actually look like coming in? What's doing the encrypting?